# Passing an ArrayList<SomeClass> to a method in a separate class as argument ArrayList<Comparable>

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I don't know the best way to phrase my question, but I'm having trouble passing an `ArrayList<class_that_implements_comparable>` to a method in a different class as an argument `ArrayList<Comparable>`.

Let's say I have two ArrayLists in a driver class:

```
ArrayList<Person> peopleList;
ArrayList<Place> placeList;
```

Both the *Person* class and the *Place* class implement Comparable.

Then, in a class called Sorts, I have two methods:

```
public static void sort(ArrayList list){
  sortList(list);
}
public static void sortList(ArrayList<Comparable> list)
{
   //Code here
}
```

With this setup, I am able to call Sorts.sort(peopleList) and Sorts.sort(placeList) without any issue. It works perfectly.

**However**, if I change the signature of the sort method to have an argument of `ArrayList<Comparable>`...

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<Comparable> list){
  sortList(list);
}
```

I get the following error in my driver class:

```
Error:(59, 14) java: method sort in class Sorts cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Comparable>
  found: java.util.ArrayList<Passenger>
  reason: actual argument java.util.ArrayList<Passenger> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Comparable> by method invocation conversion
```

Why does java allow me to pass a generic `ArrayList<>` to another class using a non-generic `ArrayList` argument and then pass that `ArrayList` to another method using an `ArrayList<Comparable>` argument, yet it won't let me pass a generic `ArrayList<>` straight to an `ArrayList<Comparable>`?

And is there a way that I can convert it directly instead of having to use an extra method?

Thank you so much for your time and any insight you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need pass something that implement Comparable itself or in superclass(or superclasses).

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(ArrayList<T> list)
```

When your method has signature static void sort(ArrayList list) it accept only instance of ArrayList.

If Person implement Comparable, it does not mean that `List<Person>` is subclass of `List<Comparable>`. So you need some extra moves to improve your method:

- allow all types that implemented Comparable `T extends Comparable`
- allow all types that inherited Comparable after superclasses `Comparable<? super T>`

Comment: Thank you! That makes total sense and helps immensely.

Comment: This does then require me to add <T extends Comparable<? super T>> to any other methods that the ArrayList gets passed to. Is there a way to remove that requirement?

Comment: Depends on your methods. If they have same idea as your `sort` method (accept all list of comparable objects), yes, you should.